# Вставить ссылку при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Пишу userscript.

Нужно на удаленный сайт, к редактированию которого у меня нет доступа, добавить ссылку (т.е., чтобы в интерфейсе сайта появилась дополнительная ссылка).

`document.write` кладет страницу, ничего более подходящего не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Создаём ссылку
var node = document.createElement("a");
//Текст для проверки
var textnode = document.createTextNode("test");
//Прикрепляем текст к ссылке
node.appendChild(textnode);
//Прикрепляем элемент списка к элементу с айдишником myList
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```

что-нибудь типа этого?

Только чтобы получить валидный ХТМЛ ссылке нужно еще атрибуты подобавлять

Comment: Спасибо. А задать ему style или хотя бы class и ссылку на удаленный файл CSS можно?

Comment: Вам поможет функция setAttribute() для установки необходимых атрибутов, таких как class и href. Также можно воспользоваться `document.getElementById("myLink").href="blablabla.com"; `